# iOS Device Orientation settings in project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode

I'm developing an Hybrid iOS application using Cordova (http://cordova.apache.org/).

I need to tweak the device orientation settings manually from the XCode project with Cordova hooks.

I was able to customise the deployment target and the targeted device family with `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` and `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` fields in `project.pbxproj` respectively, however, can't seem to find how to change orientation settings from there.

I applied the same process that I used to discover the above fields:

- Take a copy of `project.pbxproj`.
- Modify the settings from within XCode.
- Take another copy of the updated `project.pbxproj`.
- Doing a `diff` between them.

However it didn't reveal any information for orientation settings change.

Are those settings saved somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

Orientation settings are found in `<project-name>-Info.plist` XML file:

```
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```